# WooCommerce tabs not working in Divi theme

Tags: javascript, css

I have a website using an old version of the Wordpress Divi theme and a woocommerce store.  Toward the bottom of the product page is a "description" and a "review" tab.  It should be populated like on this page:
http://rattletree.com/wordpress2/product/joy-ep/

There is css there that says this:

```
<div class="panel entry-content wc-tab" style="display: block;">
```

When the tab is selected, it has `display: block;` and when a different tab is selected, it changes to `display: none;`.

That's how it should work.  I'm building our new website and using a newer version of Divi, and the contents of the tab are not visible.  I can see in the code, that they are staying on `display: none;`.

Here is the site that is not working:
https://learnmarimba.com/product/joy-ep/

Since this is a dynamic change, I guess this is being handled with javascript and not css, so I don't really know what I need to do to fix this?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have tried disabling all plugins and clearing cache, and noting has fixed the issue.  I saw this thread: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/woocommerce-review-description-tabs-not-working, and it looks like my issue, but changing the function per that thread did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE:

In `wp-content/themes/Divi/js/custom.js:2644` change `false` to `true`. It might fix your problem. If it does, it's a known and reported to Divi bug that will most likely be fixed in their next release.

As line numbers are prone to change, this is where you should make the change:

```
//...
if ( $(this).closest( '.woocommerce-tabs' ).length && $(this).closest( '.tabs' ).length ) {
    return false;
}
//...
```

---

<strike>Most probably this is due to a mismatch between your product template and the WooCommerce plugin. At some point, the class for tabs has been changed from `woocommerce_tabs` to `woocommerce-tabs`. From the looks of it, it seems like the template is ahead of the plugin. Either replace the `woocommerce-tabs` with `woocommerce_tabs` in your template file (if, for some reason, you don't want to update WC) or update WC (recommended).</strike>

From the info you provided, I can't be sure this will work, but it's worth a try.

Apart from this, one of your plugins is minifying and caching `.js` files rendering them undebugable. Maybe you should disable it during development?

Comment: Thank you.  I just disabled the caching plugin that is doing the minifying.  From what I can tell, I have the most up to date version of both Woocommerce and Divi.  I am using achild theme, so I think if I have to make a change it would be best to do it in the child theme.  Any help on that end would be greatly appreciated, and I'll try and track down where that woocommerce_tabs is happening.

Comment: There is a section in Woo that's listing all the templates used by your child+parent themes. Have you checked it? If it finds any deprecated templates (based on their declared versions), it lets you know.

Comment: I'm using Divi theme.  I'm not using a Woo theme (just their woocommerce plugin).  I'm sorry if I'm misunderstanding your question.  I just made a child theme of Divi and currently it just has some of my own CSS.

Comment: Where do you see the change from woocommerce_tabs to woocommerce-tabs?  I am only seeing woocommerce-tabs in the source code.

Comment: I was assuming you had an older version of WC and the `.js` was using the old class, since js was obfuscated. I striked that and updated with a possible solution.

Comment: That did it!  Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I took the liberty of changing the question name to better index it for  people looking for a fix to this bug.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone coming back to this in the future, in Divi Version: 2.7.x you can fix this by removing/commenting out the following code in `wp-content/themes/Divi/js/custom.js`:

```
$( 'a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])' ).click( function() {
        var $this_link = $( this ),
            has_closest_smooth_scroll_disabled = $this_link.closest( '.et_smooth_scroll_disabled' ).length,
            has_closest_woocommerce_tabs = ( $this_link.closest( '.woocommerce-tabs' ).length && $this_link.closest( '.tabs' ).length ),
            has_closest_eab_cal_link = $this_link.closest( '.eab-shortcode_calendar-navigation-link' ).length,
            has_acomment_reply = $this_link.hasClass( 'acomment-reply' ),
            disable_scroll = has_closest_smooth_scroll_disabled || has_closest_woocommerce_tabs || has_closest_eab_cal_link || has_acomment_reply;

        if ( ( location.pathname.replace( /^\//,'' ) == this.pathname.replace( /^\//,'' ) && location.hostname == this.hostname ) && ! disable_scroll ) {
            var target = $( this.hash );
            target = target.length ? target : $( '[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']' );
            if ( target.length ) {

                et_pb_smooth_scroll( target, false, 800 );

                if ( ! $( '#main-header' ).hasClass( 'et-fixed-header' ) && $( 'body' ).hasClass( 'et_fixed_nav' ) && $( window ).width() > 980 ) {
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        et_pb_smooth_scroll( target, false, 40, 'linear' );
                    }, 780 );
                }

                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```